# multiple duplicate class found in modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, pre-signed-url

I just added:

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk:1.11.404'
```

into my build.gradle and got these errors.

```
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AbortedException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException$ErrorType found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceClient found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceRequest found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.AmazonWebServiceResponse found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
Duplicate class com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration found in modules jetified-aws-android-sdk-core-2.22.2-runtime (com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.22.2) and jetified-aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.404 (com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.404)
... (many more duplicated)
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that you're already using the AWS Mobile SDK for Android. However, you've added another dependency from the AWS Java SDK v1, a different product. If you're building for Android, only use dependencies named like `aws-android-sdk-*`. See the documentation, [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/sdk/q/platform/android).